# Git pre post hook but only when files in a directory change

Tags: git

I am working in a contract with an insanely large repo that has all languages and everything under the sun in the same repo.

So we might have

```
root
   |___ Feature
              |
              |_  api
              |_ Frontend
   |___ Feature
```

Is it possible to have a git hook that is triggered when only there are changes in the `Frontend` folder above and does not run when anything else has run?

Comment: The hook is invoked by a git command instead of by the changes. Some of them can be bypassed if a special option is passed to the command. But you can do something in the hook if only there are changes in the Frontend folder and simply exit the hook if the changes are not in Frontend.

Answer (score 1):

No, hooks are per project (some web development environments like Gitlab allow global hooks but still not per directory hooks).

Why do you want one? You are not satisfied with the speed? My advice would be to write separate per directory hooks and one real hook in a compiled language (C/C++/Go) that checks what subproject it's operating on and runs a corresponding per directory hook.